# Array.from doesn't work as a direct callback function in Array#map

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've discovered some very odd behavior from `Array.from`. It appears that it does not work as a callback function directly when mapped over an array of Array-like objects. I've tested in Chrome.

Here's some test code (ES6):

```
const fails = () => {
  const x = {
    0: 'help',
    length: 1
  };

  const y = [x].map(Array.from); // will throw an Error
  return y;
};

const works = () => {
  const x = {
    0: 'help',
    length: 1
  };

  const y = [x].map(item => Array.from(item)); // will work
  return y;
};

console.log(works());
console.log(fails());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dox6wnya/

This is very peculiar behavior. I'm wondering *why* this happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.map` passes *three* arguments to its callback (`currentValue`, `index`, `array`), and `.from` accepts three arguments (`arrayLike`, `mapFn`, `thisArg`). The types of arguments don't match and/or produce unexpected results; in particular "`0 is not a function`", where `0` is the `index` argument passed to `mapFn`. The only real compatible argument is the first one, which is why it's the only one you should pass.

Comment: Why do I only see 2 args on [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?

Comment: `map` ***takes*** two args but ***passes*** three args to `callback`.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. Thanks.